# Socket.io behind load balancer

Tags: node.js, azure, nginx, socket.io, load-balancing

I am using socket.io behind nginx which is behind azure load balancer. How ever On the client side I am constantly getting errors like

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://**********/socket.io/?    session_id=i9bk_iqkVrUveKwvIBz4fMNDbkoYuaITQ_APO73sgQd6-tQBaRkjp8RR8N9LTA5LnqMeKXzZg5AXXgjEevFKqSKRJJI8iaK3&id=dc978ae038af4746baf68ead35d182f4&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=61LGLpdw53xaMYqBAAJR' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

Also nginx gives the error below

```
[error] 15348#0: *84812 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.100.50.14, server: _, request: "GET /prod/socket.io/?session_id=nR0P30IDeUutoavDyjcqAQ8hUw_3l7dtAHQ3tqzW4zVT8eBOxwbHZq_7mWd9K7qRNO2Aq45QXm8w2KSvzyFlq3O4w7P2tl2q&id=955bb63a4f804b42b9d85ac8cf9172a7&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xXGRnAsjKX6Gj-SAAAls HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?session_id=nR0P30IDeUutoavDyjcqAQ8hUw_3l7dtAHQ3tqzW4zVT8eBOxwbHZq_7mWd9K7qRNO2Aq45QXm8w2KSvzyFlq3O4w7P2tl2q&id=955bb63a4f804b42b9d85ac8cf9172a7&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xXGRnAsjKX6Gj-SAAAls"
```

Anyone have an idea about the reason?

Nginx conf:

```
proxy_pass http://lb-prod/; # Load balance the URL location "/" to the upstream lb1
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: nginx has to be specifically configured for webSockets in order for them to work properly.  Have you done that?  You can read here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: I believe I have done so, I have edited the post to show my conf

Comment: Some nginx instructions [here](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) for socket.io load balancing.  There's more there than you show above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was about session stickyness. Configuring my load balancer to use **sticky session** solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/) from Nginx offical website which is the best practice for using NGINX and NGINX Plus with Node.js and Socket.IO.

I think it's very helpful for you now.